# square detection enhancement

Tags: android, opencv, computer-vision, edge-detection

I am developing a currency identification system for blind people. I need to check if the full currency note has been captured so I used square detection for that.  It is currently working when the background is pure black or white, but not when the background is more advanced. What techniques can I use to solve this problem?

I am using OpenCV as my image processing framework. Can I use convolution? How?

`need enhancement for square detection.`

Result image of my code:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether rectangle detection is the best solution for what you want to do.

It will only work efficiently if the picture is taken right up from the money, and as you say will not be robust to cluttered backgrounds.

Is there a precise reason for not going to a direct pattern recognition system ? 
I'd start with a picture of my currency and try to perform object recognition with it.

You will find loads of tutorials that can help you on the web, [like for bottles](http://achuwilson.wordpress.com/2011/02/13/object-detection-using-opencv-using-haartraining/) or for [bowls](http://lab.cntl.kyutech.ac.jp/~kobalab/nishida/opencv/OpenCV_ObjectDetection_HowTo.pdf).

You might have a lot of possibilities, due to the number of currencies but you know it to be a finite number at least.

Comment: Thank you for responding to my question.i am new to opencv and my knowledge is also poor. this is for my final year project. time is critical factor too. the problem i have is the image prosessing is done in gray scale image. how the color difference effect for that? object regognition is all new technique for me :(.can u suggest some thing??

Comment: Well, I don't see any problem in there. Color seem not to be a good feature to rely on in your case (money color tends to change depending on face value), but texture should be similar. Plus grayscale will fasten your processing time compared to color. A good point to start is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_detection_(computer_vision) and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform. You'll find plenty of OpenCV documentqtion for thqt ;). Good luck !